# Yodlee transactions originating from joint bank/credit card accounts

Tags: yodlee

Imagine a scenario where two people hold a joint account. Each person signs up for an individual account on a web application which in turn creates two individual consumer accounts with Yodlee. Both people proceed to add their joint account via FaskLink, each with their respective bank/credit card credentials.

So now we have a single joint account linked to two Yodlee consumer accounts. Will this cause all items/transactions in that joint account to be duplicated across the two individual Yodlee accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it has been aggregated with two different set of credentials. It will be treated as two separate accounts and you'll see the duplicates.

Comment: I notice the transactions are duplicated for both holders of a joint account with a different transactionId for their respective itemAccountId. Is there any way within Yodlee's services to determine which joint account holder is responsible for a duplicated transaction?

Comment: Additionally, it appears as if only certain transactions are duplicated. I'm examining 28 days of transactions from a joint bank account. User #1 shows 27 transactions. User #2 shows 6 transactions. These 6 transactions are duplicated for User #1 but the remaining 21 transactions are **not** duplicated for User #2. What might be happening here?

Comment: @JoshuaM- Ideally this should not happen. Could you please connect over the Chat option available on Developer portal.